# Should answers which contain only dead links be removed?

Tags: discussion, flags

If an answer only contains a dead link and no other useful information should it be flagged for removal?

For an example of what I mean see the the answer from Zian Choy on:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227987/roadmap-for-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 3):

The link works for me. At any rate, adding a comment stating that it does not work or editing if the link is found in a new place would be the best course of action. This is why normally snippet of content is added in order to guard against link rot.

Comment: Actually you point out a good fact.  This link is actually lying.  It's supposed to be a discussion about one topic (ASP.Net MVC 4 roadmap) but in fact points to something entirely different.

Comment: @Shane: Yea, looks like a problem with the ASP.NET forum possibly.